# How to prove that $\forall a\in\mathbb R^+: \frac{\int_a^\infty x\cdot e^{-x^2/2}dx}{\int_a^\infty e^{-x^2/2}dx}\le a + \sqrt{2/\pi}$?

Tags: probability, inequality, normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $a\in\mathbb R^+$ and $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$.

I want to prove that
$$\mathbb E[X | X\ge a] = \frac{\int_a^\infty x\cdot e^{-x^2/2}dx}{\int_a^\infty e^{-x^2/2}dx}\le a + \sqrt{2/\pi}.$$

Any ideas/directions?

---

Playing with it in Wolfram Alpha, it seems that the inequality hold, with equality for $a=0$.

Comment: You are facing two simple integrals. Did you solve them ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - Simple :)? One doesn't have a closed form formula.

Comment: Make $x^2=t$ in the top one. The bottom is well known. In fact, what they almost want you to prove is that $\pi >2$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - Yes, the top one has a closed form formula $e^{-a^2/2}$. This doesn't get me anywhere closer. Both are well known: the pdf and cdf of the normal distribution (this is what you get when computing conditional expectation. So?). There's no "they" (I came across this problem trying to prove some property of random rotations)).
I also didn't get your point about $\pi>2$. You seem to be convinced that there's a trivial solution, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Think about series expansion of the lhs

Comment: Do the same for $a\to \infty$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - can you please explain how the expansion around $a=0$ and $a\to\infty$ help establish the result for all $a$?
Wolfram gives both, but I'm not sure how to proceed.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expansion+of++%28e%5E%28-a%5E2%2F2%29%2F+int_a%5Einf+%28e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29dx%29%29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof based on know asymptotics for $P[X>a]$ as $a\rightarrow\infty$ to establish the validity of the statement for large $a$, and then, using  differential Calculus to establish the validity of the statement for all $a\geq0$.

> ***Theorem F:***  Let $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$. Then
> $$\Big(\frac1a-\frac1{a^3}\big)\phi(a)\leq 1-F(a)\leq \frac1a\phi(a)$$

**Proof of Theorem F:** This can be obtained by integrating the inequalities
$$(1-3x^{-4})\phi(x)\leq \phi(x)\leq (1+x^{-2})\phi(x)$$
over $[a,\infty)$. See Feller, Introduction to Probability, Vol 1, 1968, section 7.1.

---

A simple substitution $u=x^2/2$ yields
$$\int^\infty_ax\phi(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-a^2/2}=\phi(a)$$

Hence, for $a>1$
$$
a\leq\frac{\phi(a)}{1-F(a)}\leq a+\frac{a}{a^2-1}
$$
Thus, the stamens is valid for all $a$ large enough.

Now consider the function
$$G(a)=\phi(a)-(a+c)\bar{F}(a),\qquad\text{where}\quad \bar{F}(a)=1-F(a),\quad c=\sqrt{2/\pi}$$
$G(0)=0$ as $c=2\phi(0)$, and $G(\infty):=\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}G(a)=0$ as $\phi(a)\xrightarrow{a\rightarrow\infty}0$ and $a\bar{F}(a)\xrightarrow{a\rightarrow\infty}0$ (by Markov-Chebyshev's inequality for example).
$$\begin{align}
G'(a)&=c\phi(a)-\bar{F}(a)\\
G''(a)&=(1-ac)\phi(a)
\end{align}$$
There is only one inflection point, namely $a_*=c^{-1}=\sqrt{\pi/2}$; moreover, it follows easily that $G$ is convex on $(-\infty,a_*]$, and concave on $[a_*,\infty)$. Since $G'(0)=\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac12<0$, $G$ is strictly monotone decreasing in an interval containing $a=0$. This, along with the facts that  $G'(\infty)=0$ and that $G(a)<0$ for all $a$ large enough, implies that $G$ cannot take positive values on $[0,\infty)$ (otherwise there would be more than one inflection points) and so, $G(a)< 0$ for all $a>0$.

Here is a graph of $G$ in the interval $[0,5]$.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer. Take $f(x) = \exp(-x^2/2)$.  Then for $x > 0$ $$f(x) = -\frac{f’(x)}x.$$

Take $a>1$ and use partial integration twice: $$\begin{eqnarray}\int_a^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm dx &=& -\int_a^{\infty}\frac{f’(x)}x\mathrm dx\\
 &=& -\left[\frac{f(x)}x\right]_a^{\infty} - \int_a^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}\mathrm dx\\
&=& \frac{f(a)}a - \int_a^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}\mathrm dx
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\int_a^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\mathrm dx &=& -\int_a^{\infty}\frac{f’(x)}{x^3}\mathrm dx\\
 &=& -\left[\frac{f(x)}{x^3}\right]_a^{\infty} - 3 \int_a^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^4}\mathrm dx\\
&=& \frac{f(a)}{a^3} - 3 \int_a^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^4}\mathrm dx < \frac{f(a)}{a^3}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Combine these two results to conclude $$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)\mathrm dx > f(a)\left(\frac1a - \frac1{a^3}\right).$$

This suffices to show your result for big enough $a$ (such that $a/(a^2-1) \leq \sqrt{2/\pi}$.)

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\int_a^\infty x\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d} x = \mathrm{e}^{-a^2/2}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$f(a) := \int_a^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
- \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-a^2/2}}{a + \sqrt{2/\pi}} \ge 0.$$

We have
$$f'(a) = -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\mathrm{e}^{-a^2/2}}{(a\sqrt{\pi} + \sqrt 2)^2}\left(a - \frac{\pi - 2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right).$$

Let $a_0 = \frac{\pi - 2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. We have
$f'(a_0) = 0$, and $f'(a) > 0$ on $(0, a_0)$,
and $f'(a) < 0$ on $(a_0, \infty)$.
Also, we have
$f(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{a\to \infty} f(a) = 0$.
Thus, $f(a) \ge 0$ on $(0, \infty)$.

We are done.