# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}{xe^{x^2}\int_{x}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}} dx}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I show $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{xe^{x^2}\int_{x}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}} dx}=\frac{1}{2}$$

I tried writing it as a fraction and applying L'Hopital's rule but it didn't lead anywhere.  Taking $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\int_{x}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}} \ dx}$ on its own is just $0$ (?) so I'm not sure how to get $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: See Feller, Introduction to Probability, Vol 1, 1968, section 7.1

Comment: L'Hospital rule works, if you express the limit as $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x\int_x^{\infty}\mathrm e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt)/\mathrm e^{-x^2}$

Comment: See Theorem $F$ in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359329/how-to-prove-that-forall-a-in-mathbb-r-frac-int-a-infty-x-cdot-e-x2-2)

Comment: @PavelR. Thanks, I'll give it a go. I was trying with $x$ on the denominator originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'Hopital works. This is an indeterminate limit of the form $0 \cdot \infty$. As you noticed $f(x) = \int_x^\infty e^{-s^2} \ ds \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Obviously $g(x) = x e^{x^2} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. So you apply the standard L'Hopital transformation for indeterminates of type $0 \cdot \infty$:
$$
\lim _{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{ f(x)}{ 1/g(x)}
$$ By FTC $f'(x) = -e^{-x^2}$ and $(1/g(x))' = (e^{-x^2}/x)' = -e^{-x^2}(2 + \frac{1}{x^2})$ So continuing from the above
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{ f(x)}{ 1/g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{ f'(x)}{ (1/g(x))'} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{ 1}{ 2 + \frac{1}{x^2}} = \frac{1}{2} 
$$